# ImportError: cannot import name 'get_recorded_queries' from 'flask_sqlalchemy' with Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I used to track SQL queries issued by Flask-SQLAlchemy at end of each request.

Since I upgraded to Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1 (from Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.0.5), I get the following import error!

```
File "/srv/api/common/auth.py", line 6, in <module>
from flask_sqlalchemy import get_recorded_queries 
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_recorded_queries' from 'flask_sqlalchemy' (/srv/api/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py)
```

Documentation of Flask-SQLAlchemy does not report any change from 3.0.5 to 3.1.1 about this function.

Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: I raised the question on the Github repository.